# Join column to multiple columns in another table

Tags: mysql

I want to join this query result `TRANSACT_CLNTAB` with columns in another table `CLNTAB`

```
SELECT t.acct_code    
FROM transact_clntab t    
group BY t.acct_code    
HAVING MAX(t.trade_date) < '2015-01-01' AND    
       MAX(t.trade_date) >= '2008-01-01'    
where transact_clntab.acct_code = clntab.acct_code'
```

This query works (without the last line) but I need to join with a new table (CLNTAB) to get complete information

```
SELECT t.*    
FROM (SELECT t.*,    
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.acct_code ORDER BY t.trade_date DESC) as seqnum    
  FROM transact_clntab t    
 ) t    
WHERE seqnum = 1 
AND   t.trade_date < '2015-01-01' 
AND   t.trade_date >= '2008-01-01';'
```

Expected answer should be

```
chn    ACCT_CODE     NAMES    ADDRESS    
65744938    .AMA-4080    Jack Steel  53, Joseph Court
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. I will post an answer once i fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What I want is to Find clients that started since 2008 and stopped trading in 2014 but hasn't done any transaction(s) from 2014 till date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238560/what-i-want-is-to-find-clients-that-started-since-2008-and-stopped-trading-in-20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` must come before `GROUP BY`.

To work with 2 tables, you need a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.acct_code    
    FROM transact_clntab t  
    JOIN clntab c  ON t.acct_code = c.acct_code
    group BY t.acct_code    
    HAVING MAX(t.trade_date)  < '2015-01-01' AND    
           MAX(t.trade_date) >= '2008-01-01'
```